# Django form 2 not loading

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to build a inventory management project facing some difficulty, Looking for a solution.
I have created a 2 form in django model and when I try to load form2 only form1  is loading for all the condition.

I have tried to comment form1 and load only form2 with that I got the expected result but when I try to add run with both the forms I am facing the issue.

Additional to this in django admin panel I am getting I am getting both the forms as expected.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Views.py

```
from .models import Inventory_Details, Incoming_QC
from .forms import MyForm, Incoming_QC_form
def my_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Submitted successfully')
            #return redirect('/home_page/')
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, "authentication/Inventory_details.html", {'form': form})

def View_Inventory(request):
    Inventory_list = Inventory_Details.objects.all()
    return render(request,'authentication/View_Inventory.html',
                  {'Inventory_list': Inventory_list})
def Incoming_qc_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        QC_form = Incoming_QC_form(request.POST)
        if QC_form.is_valid():
            QC_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Submitted successfully')
            #return redirect('/home_page/')
    else:
        QC_form = Incoming_QC_form()
    return render(request, "authentication/Incoming_QC.html", {'QC_form': QC_form})



def View_Incoming_QC(request):
    Incoming_QC_list = Incoming_QC.objects.all()
    return render(request,'authentication/View_Incoming_QC.html',
                  {'Incoming_QC_list': Incoming_QC_list})
```

urls.py

```
url(r'form', views.my_form, name='form'),
    path('View_Inventory', views.View_Inventory, name="View_Inventory"),
    url(r'QC_form', views.Incoming_qc_form, name='QC_form'),
    path('View_Incoming_QC', views.View_Incoming_QC, name="View_Incoming_QC")
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    body {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
{% csrf_token %}
{% load static %}
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="/home_page">Home</a>
    <a href="/QC_form">Incoming Quality Check</a>
    <a href="/form">Inventory Store Management</a>
    <a href="/View_Inventory">Inventory Details</a>
    <a href="/View_Incoming_QC"> Incoming QC details</a>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
</div>
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        <fieldset style="margin-block:15px">
            <legend>Incoming_QC</legend>
            {% csrf_token %}
        {{ QC_form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Inventory_Details, Incoming_QC


class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Inventory_Details

    fields = ["Invoice_number",
              "AWB",
              "Received_from",
              "Description",
              "Quantity",
              "Received_date",
              "Received_by",
              "Assigned_To",
              "Manufacturing_PN",]
    labels = {'Invoice_number': "Invoice_number",
              'AWB':"AWB",
              'Received_from':"Received_from",
              'Description':"Description",
              'Quantity':"Quantity",
              'Received_date':"Received_date",
              'Received_by':"Received_by",
              'Assigned_To':"Assigned_To",
              'Manufacturing_PN':"Manufacturing_PN",
              'Manufacturer':"Manufacturer",
              }


class Incoming_QC_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Incoming_QC

        fields = ["Manufacturer",
              "Location",
              "Inspected_By",
              "Conducted_On",
              "Supplier_name",
              "Supplier_address",
              "PO_number",
              "Material_name",
              "Part_number",
              "Quantity",
              ]

        labels = {'Manufacturer': "Manufacturer",
              'Location': "Location",
              'Inspected_By': "Inspected_By",
              'Conducted_On': "Conducted_On",
              'Supplier_name': "Supplier_name",
              'Supplier_address': "Supplier_address",
             'PO_number': "PO_number",
             'Material_name': "Material_name",
             'Part_number': "Part_number",
             'Quantity': "Quantity",
             }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Form which view the form2 is not loading

Comment: Incoming_qc_form is not loading

Comment: means it is not displaying on template?

Comment: Yes exactly. When I call QC_form in my html file the form1 is loading which is my_form

Comment: show me forms.py file related to this

Comment: Are you getting any error on template

Comment: No I am not getting any error

Comment: When I click on Incoming Quality Check and Inventory Store Management both the time it is calling /form but as I have given in html file for Incoming Quality check it should call /QC_form and for Inventory Store Management it should call /form

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<a href="/QC_form">Incoming Quality Check</a>
<a href="/form">Inventory Store Management</a>
```

Try this:

```
<a href="{% url 'QC_form' %}">Incoming Quality Check</a>
<a href="{% url 'form' %}">Inventory Store Management</a>
```

I think the problem is in view.

Simply try this:

```
def Incoming_qc_form(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        qcform = Incoming_QC_form(request.POST)
        if qcform.is_valid():
            qcform.save()
            return HttpResponse('Submitted successfully')
            #return redirect('/home_page/')
    else:
        qcform = Incoming_QC_form()
    return render(request, "authentication/Incoming_QC.html", {'qcform': qcform})
```

And in template:

```
{{qcform}}
```

Comment: Tried with your answer but no luck still facing the same issue

Comment: I think the problem is in view. because of two underscore of form name it is not loading.

Comment: I have updated my answer try that. modified form name in QC form view

Comment: Hi Thanks for your efforts, but still same issue I am facing. And in IDE I am getting this [24/Nov/2022 05:29:46] "GET /qc_form HTTP/1.1" 200 3583 I think it's pointing to qc-form but not loading the form

Comment: Now you are getting 200 ok in terminal but it is not loading in template right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: In forms.py just change the name instead of this Incoming_QC_form to this IncomingQcForm

Comment: And in views.py: change the name instead of this Incoming_qc_form to this IncomingQcForm

Comment: class name and function name must be in correct format

Comment: Tried with your suggestions still same issue

Comment: Last thing try this: instead of this: qcform = Incoming_QC_form(request.POST) Try this: qcform = QcForm(request.POST)

Comment: Tried your solution. No luck